# how to add xmpp or matrix protocols on webbrowser like Lynx or with python webbrowser?

Tags: python, matrix, xmpp, protocols, lynx

i have no idea how to add xmpp or matrix protocols on Lynx-likes and python webbrowser, is it possible ? how ?
i only know how to do with http protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not really possible because you would need Javascript on the client side to do the XML Processing. But if you want to chat in your terminal you could use [Profanity](https://profanity-im.github.io/) or [Poezio](https://poez.io/en/) for XMPP.